# How to use lubricate's %within% in conjunction with dplyr?

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, intervals

I'm trying to filter sensor data which are present in "inactive working shifts". Meaning I want to compare every DateTime element of a data frame to a list of intervals to check if the sensor data was recorded during such a shift.

I'm building all time intervals like so:

```
INAS_intervals <- raw_sensor_data %>%
            filter(error_code == "INAS") %>%
            summarise(inactive = interval(ymd_hms(from), ymd_hms(to)))
```

Resulting in:

```
inactive
<S4: Interval>
2019-08-03 06:00:00 UTC--2019-08-03 12:30:00 UTC                
2019-08-03 12:30:00 UTC--2019-08-04 06:00:00 UTC                
2019-08-04 06:00:00 UTC--2019-08-04 12:30:00 UTC
```

Building the filter like this (broken):

```
saw %>%  
  filter(any(dateTime %within% INAS_intervals)) %>%
  mutate(diffi = abs(machSpeed - curMachSpeed)) 
 (...)


> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length...
```

Why is it not possible to use %within% with the column 'dateTime' (type: POSIXct) like this?

Side-note:

```
any(saw[1,1] %within% INAS_intervals)

>Error in saw[1, 1] %within% INAS_intervals : 
  No %within% method with signature a = tbl_df,  b = tbl_df
```

But this works fine:

```
any(saw[[1,1]] %within% INAS_intervals)

[1] FALSE
```

Do I have to use lapply(), sapply() or apply() in this case? I am very unexperienced in using this technique. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, it needs a `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)
saw %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  filter(dateTime %within% INAS_intervals) %>%
  ungroup %>%
   mutate(diffi = abs(machSpeed - curMachSpeed))
```